# what is the difference between passing SQL query in createstatement() and execute()?

Tags: java, jdbc

[In both cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950245/difference-between-createstatement-and-preparedstatement-in-jdbc/%22related%20topic%22) same thing happens i.e(insertion/manipulation of data). But what happens internally?

Passing the Query in execute():

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","dinga");

        String str="insert into student values(10,'abc',100)";

        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

        stmt.execute(str); //Passing query in execute()

        System.out.println("Data inserted successfully");
```

Passing the Query in CreateStatement()

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","dinga");

        String str="insert into student values(10,'abc',100)";

        Statement stmt=con.createStatement(str);//Passing Query in createStatement()

        stmt.execute();

        System.out.println("Data inserted successfully");
```

Comment: In your case, probably not a great deal, but `PreparedStatement` can help prevent possible SQL-Injection attacks. When used properly (ie with parameters), there is also the possibility of improved performance, as the database can cache the access plan. The long and short of it is, you should use `PreparedStatement`s as much as possible - it's good habit and prevents you from making accidental mistakes.  The parameterised support also makes it easier when dealing with object/type mappings (date/time especially)

Comment: A better example, in you case, would have been to use a query like `String str="insert into student values(?,?,?)";`, you would have then been required to bind the parameters via the `PreparedStatement`

Comment: The difference is that you get a **compile error** in the second case: `con.createStatement(str)` doesn't compile because there is no `createStatement` method that takes a String argument. You may be thinking of the `prepareStatement` method - the name of that method should already give you a hint what's different between that method and `createStatement` - reading the Javadoc of both methods should fill you in on the rest of the difference.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for documentation. The Java API is extensively documented, you should read it before asking questions like this.

Answer (score -3):

There is no difference except readability in this case :P

Comment: There is a difference, the first compiles and the second doesn't.